# What does RO mean?

Tags: legalese, finance

English is not my mother tongue and now I am reading [a financial article](http://www.anz.com/vietnam/en/corporate/first-time-investors/finance-regulations/) about the banking industry in Vietnam. In it a line says the following:

> This Section focuses only on the commercial banks which consist of
>   State-run banks, joint stock banks, joint venture banks, foreign bank
>   branches, and **foreign bank ROs**.

I now wonder what an RO is. Does anybody know what an RO in this context is? All tips are welcome!

Comment: I'd guess "regional offices" given the context.

Comment: @Mat - Or could it also be "remote operations" or something?

Comment: http://www.acronymfinder.com/RO.html

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about ELU

Answer (score 1):

The ANZ website's [About Us](http://www.anz.com/vietnam/en/about%2Dus/our%2Dcompany/anz%2Dvietnam/) page lists

> Eight branches and transaction office locations
>   One representative office
>   Nation-wide ATM network
>   Extensive EFTPOS network

...so it would appear to mean ***representative office***. Quite what a "representative office" actually **is** is anyone's guess. Presumably it's an office which doesn't offer transactional/cash-handling facilities but where there are staff who manage accounts and applications for them.